# Postman: Use the request name within the declaration of an environment variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamic, postman

I would like to use Postman to set an Environment variable in a dynamic way and use the dataObject..attribute2's values based on the request name. This script is used within the Pre-req section.

Situation:
I have a json data object:

```
var dataObject = {

    "request01": {
        "attribute1": 123456789,
        "attribute2": "asdfghjkl"
    },
    "request02": {
        "attribute1": 987654321,
        "attribute2": "lkjhgfdsa"
    }
}
```

And I have these 2 requests in the same folder with the names:

- request01
- request02

Now, I want to define the value of this allocation, so I assign the attribute2 value to the variable dynamicAttribute2.
If I do this in a static way it is like this:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("dynamicAttribute2", dataObject.request02.attribute2);
```

Now this question how to do it properly in a dynamic way, depending on the request name, each.
I tried to do this:

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("dynamicAttribute2", dataObject.{request.info.name}.attribute2);
```

The issue is that Postman cannot resolve the object reference to the attribute.

**Question**

What's the correct way to use this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax to get the `Request Name` is:

`pm.info.requestName`

So you would need to use something like this to get the value you want:

```
pm.environment.set("dynamicAttribute2", dataObject[`${pm.info.requestName}`].attribute2);
```

It might be worth you taking a look through this to learn more about the `pm.*` API functions:

https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/#pm

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically access an object's key (to retrieve the property or set it) using square brackets, similar to arrays. This should work:

```js
postman.setEnvironmentVariable(
  "dynamicAttribute2",
  dataObject[request.info.name].attribute2
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if I use this 
```
console.log(
"dynamicAttribute2: " + dataObject[request.info.name].attribute2
);
```
I get the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"